# how to get value of dyanically created hidden field in angular JS

Tags: jquery, angularjs, laravel

Hi i am working on laravel , i am using angular JS. in my class module i have to add hidden filed and textbox dynamically i have done it but when i submit the form with ng-submit its not posting the dynamically create field value here is the my code

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="addDorm" role="form" ng-submit="saveAdd()" novalidate>

      <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label ng-binding">Subject *</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="input-group">
            <select class="form-control ng-dirty ng-valid ng-valid-required" ng-model="form.classSubjects" name="classSubjects" id="classSubjects" required="">
              <!-- ngRepeat: (key, value) in subject --><option class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-repeat="(key, value) in subject" value="1">Physics</option><!-- end ngRepeat: (key, value) in subject --><option class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-repeat="(key, value) in subject" value="2">math</option><!-- end ngRepeat: (key, value) in subject -->
            </select>
            <span class="input-group-addon add_btn"><a href="#" id="dayvisitStudents" class="btn btn-primary">+</a></span>
        </div>
      </div>



    </div>
    <div id="sbjectDetail">
            <table id="dayvist1" style="width:26% !important; margin-left:195px;"  class="table table-bordered"> 
                <thead> 
                    <tr> 
                        <th>Subjects</th> 

                    </tr> 
                </thead> 
                <tbody>
                    <tr> 
                        <td style="width:50%"></td> 

                    </tr> 
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
```

and here is my jquery to add dynamically filed

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var iCnt = 0;
$('#dayvisitStudents').click(function(e){
    var subtext =$("#classSubjects option:selected").text();
    var subId =$("#classSubjects").val();
    iCnt = iCnt + 1
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents().find('td:first-child').append('<div id="dvd'+iCnt+'" class="multi-inputs"><span><input class="form-control  txtsub txtBtn" value="'+subtext+'"  type="text" readonly ng-model="form.clsSubjectsnametxt" name="clsSubjectsnametxt"></span><a id="rmvicon" class="btn btn-primary " data-value="'+iCnt+'">-</a><input type="hidden" name="clsSubjectsnew" ng-model="form.clsSubjectsnew" value="'+subId+'"></div>');
});
    $(document).on('click', '#rmvicon', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id=$(this).attr("data-value");
    //$('#dvd'+id).remove();
    $(this).parents().find('#dvd'+id).remove();
//  $(this).parents().find('td:first-child').append('<div class="multi-inputs"><input class="form-control txtBtn"  type="text" name="dayvisitStudents[]"><a class="btn btn-primary ">X</a></div>');
});
```

please help me i am new for laravel and agular js both .thanks in adavnce

Comment: I'm not a fan of using jQuery with angular when it isn't necessary.  I would use ng-show or ng-if to show the hidden elements

Comment: Hi jbrown but my requirement is add multiple field dynamically not show and hide .

Comment: For multiple dynamic elements you should use a directive.  Directives are the place for DOM manipulation in angular.

Comment: can you post some example how to use Directives for multiple dynamic elements becuase i am new in angular, thank you for the replay

Comment: You can find all sorts of examples online but here's a simple plunker that I threw together https://plnkr.co/edit/ww1rH72zFYQC3dqhfCIr?p=info